# Decision Trees with R

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree

I ran that example from the rpart-manpage

```
tree <- rpart(Species~., data = iris)
plot(tree,margin=0.1)
text(tree)
```

Now I want to modify that, for another dataset

```
digitstrainURL <- "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pendigits/pendigits.tra"
digitsTestURL <- "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pendigits/pendigits.tes"
digitstrain <- read.table(digitstrainURL, sep=",",
                          col.names=c("i1","i2","i3","i4","i5","i6","i7","i8","i9","i10","i11","i12","i13","i14","i15","i16", "Class"))
digitstest <- read.table(digitsTestURL, sep=",",
col.names=c("i1","i2","i3","i4","i5","i6","i7","i8","i9","i10","i11","i12","i13","i14","i15","i16", "Class"))

tree <- rpart(Class~., data = digitstrain)
plot(tree,margin=0.1)
text(tree)
```

The dataset contains data for handwriten digits, and the "Class" holds the Digit 0-9
But when I plot the Tree, I get weired floating point numbers as result, any Idea what these numbers mean? I would prefer to have 0-9 as text for the leafs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to fit a classification tree, but your data is integers, not factors.

The function `rpart` will try to guess what method to use, and in your case is making the wrong guess.  So your code fits a tree based on `method="anova"`, whereas you want to use `method="class"`.

Try this:

```
tree <- rpart(Class~., data = digitstrain, method="class")
plot(tree,margin=0.1)
text(tree, cex=0.7)
```

[image]

To test the accuracy of your model, you can use `predict` to get predicted values and then create a confusion matrix:

```
confusion <- data.frame(
  class=factor(digitstest$Class), 
  predict=predict(tree, digitstest, type="class")
  )
with(confusion, table(class, predict))

     predict
class   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
    0 311   1   0   0   0   0   0   7  42   2
    1   0 139 186   4   0   0   0   1  10  24
    2   0   0 320  14   2   3   0   7  15   3
    3   0   6   0 309   1   3   0  17   0   0
    4   0   1   0   5 300   0   0   0   0  58
    5   0   0   0  74   0 177   0   1  14  69
    6   5   0   3   9  12   0 264  11   5  27
    7   2   9  11  13   0  10   0 290   0  29
    8  60   0   0   0   0  32   0  21 220   3
    9   1  44   0   9  20   0   0   8   0 254
```

Note that the prediction using a single tree isn't great.  A very easy way to improve the prediction is to use a random forest, consisting of many trees fitted with random subsets of your training data:

```
library(randomForest)

fst <- randomForest(factor(Class)~., data = digitstrain, method="class")
```

Observe that the forest gives far superior prediction results:

```
confusion <- data.frame(
  class=factor(digitstest$Class), 
  predict=predict(fst, digitstest, type="class")
  )
with(confusion, table(class, predict))

     predict
class   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
    0 347   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  16   0
    1   0 333  28   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
    2   0   5 359   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    3   0   4   0 331   0   0   0   0   0   1
    4   0   0   0   0 362   1   0   0   0   1
    5   0   0   0   8   0 316   0   0   0  11
    6   1   0   0   0   0   0 335   0   0   0
    7   0  26   2   0   0   0   0 328   0   8
    8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 336   0
    9   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   2   1 331
```

Comment: Thanks alot! shouldn't the result fit for all training data?
I picked some data and checked it on my own, but it does not give me the right result. Is there a possibility to feed the tree with data and get a result?

Comment: @user2071938 A single tree is not going to guarantee a good model, but a random forest model will in general perform better.  I have expanded my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because your Class column is numeric. Convert it to factor then try...

```
digitstrain$Class = as.factor(digitstrain$Class)
tree <- rpart(Class~., data = digitstrain)
plot(tree,margin=0.1)
text(tree)
```

Result would be

[image]